# Project Euler #5 in Java: stuck in the end of program

Tags: java

I am trying to get the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 20. But somehow I am stuck in the end of the program. My answer is coming 40 which is wrong. Here is my code:

```
public class Lessons {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n;
        int s = 0;

        for (n = 21; n > 0; n++) 
        {
         for (int m = 1; m <= 20; m++) 
           {
                s = n % m;
            }
            if (s == 0) 
             {
                System.out.println(n);
                break;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Any helps???

Comment: Thing would be easier, for you and for us, @Vaibhav, if you had indented this code correctly.

Comment: Sorry for improper coding. Corrected it.

Comment: Never mind, @Vaibhav. I'm too strict when it comes to indentation and organization in general. It helps a lot. One may take care only of the complexities of the problem, without risking syntax problems.

Comment: @VaibhavAgarwal i hope this approach helps you to understand [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35618229/project-euler-5-in-java-stuck-in-the-end-of-program/40122859#40122859][link here]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're effectively only ever checking whether `n%20 == 0`. This loop:

```
for (int m = 1; m <= 20; m++) {
    s = n % m;
}
```

does run for m from 1 to 20, but you always overwrite `s` and never do anything with the value before resetting it the next time through the loop. You need to check the result of `n % m` for each iteration of the loop, perhaps like:

```
    for (n = 21; n > 0; n++) {
        bool divisibleByAll = true;

        for (int m = 1; m <= 20; m++) {
            s = n % m;

            if(s != 0) {
                divisibleByAll = false;
                break; //don't bother checking the rest
            }
        }

        if (divisibleByAll) {
            System.out.println(n);
            break;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is NOT correct either. You should reject a number when s != 0, because it is then that it is not divisibleByAll.

Comment: @EddeAlmeida Thanks. Must have more coffee.

Comment: I made above mentioned changes. But this time nothing is returned by program.

Answer (score 1):

> another option with brute force and modulo rest-classification

this problem can be solved with a simple common modulo rest class characteristrics.
look at the numbers from 1 to 20 and divide it into two groups and find some unique common attributes between them.

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

```
   we are building division with the same reminder members
```

1 divides all

2 divide 4,8 -->>8 important

3 divide 6,9 but 6 doesnt divide 9 evenly--> 6,9

5 divide 10-->> 10 important

that leaves us with 6,7,8,9,10 to check if there is any number from 1 that can divide this with rest 0.

the trick is if 2,4,8 divides a number let say 16 with the same reminder then we dont have to check if 2,4 divides 16, we check only 8.

11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20

hier were can do the same from about with factors of the numbers from above and we will be left with

11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20

> NB: we know that the last number that has to divide the number is 20,
>   so that mean either the solution will be a number ending with 0 or is
>   one of the factors of 20, so we build factors of 20 and check if 11 12
>   13 14 15 16 17 18 19 can divide it then we are done.

```
int start = 20;

    while (start % 11 != 0 || start % 12 != 0 | start % 13 != 0 || start % 14 != 0 || 
            start % 15 != 0 || start % 16 != 0 || start % 17 != 0 || start % 18 != 0 || start % 19 != 0 )
    {
        start += 20;
    }
    System.out.println("The smallest number is: "+start);
```

> The same idea applies analog to the first deduction i made to make the
>   problem seems smaller.

//smallest number divisible by all numbers from 1 to 10

```
int a = 10;

    while (a % 6 != 0 || a % 7 != 0 | a % 8 != 0 || a % 9 != 0 )
    {
        a += 10;
    }

System.out.println("The smallest number is: "+a);
```

//smallest number divisible by all numbers from 1 to 5

```
int i = 5;                          

    while (i % 3 != 0 || i % 4 != 0)
    {
        i += 5;
    }

System.out.println("The smallest number is: "+ i);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for ( int i = 2520; ; i += 2520 ){
            if (     i % 11 == 0 && 
                     i % 12 == 0 && 
                     i % 13 == 0 && 
                     i % 14 == 0 && 
                     i % 15 == 0 && 
                     i % 16 == 0 && 
                     i % 17 == 0 && 
                     i % 18 == 0 && 
                     i % 19 == 0 && 
                     i % 20 == 0 ){
                long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                System.out.println("Answer: " + i + "\nIt took "+(stopTime - startTime) + " milliseconds");
                break;
            }
        }
```

This takes 1 - 2 milliseconds on average. I know its a lame ass solution but hey it works.